# How do you run equivalent of nested for loops in scheme

Tags: loops, scheme, nested-loops, idioms, code-translation

I am looking on how to translate this pseudocode to idiomatic scheme:

```
for c in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(1, c):
        for a in range(1, b):
            do something if condition is true
```

Comment: Translating meaningless syntax leads to unidiomatic code.

Comment: It's kind of sad (but probably correct) this got closed because it offers a great example to show what macros can do.

Comment: see e.g. [this](http://community.schemewiki.org/?syntax-dotimes). without the macros, it also mentions the "named let", e.g. like https://pastebin.com/U8ai7hLs

Comment: @tfb I voted to reopen.

Comment: @WillNess: I just have too (sorry I didn't know you could despite the obvious button).  I think it's worth it because there are potential interesting answers which show how linguistically powerful Lisp-family languages are, although this may only be because I have a macro which does this...

Comment: it's simple enough without any macros too, just some nested named lets too can do it.

Comment: @WillNess: of course.  But a macro can make the syntax go away.

Comment: @tfb Here I paste a problem that I struggle to elegantly express in scheme (with my solutions in scheme and python): https://pastebin.com/67GT8ep2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode is translated into Scheme straightforwardly enough as a sequence of nested named `let`s, as

```lisp
(let loopc ((c 1))                ; start the top loop with c = 1,
  (if (> c 1000)                  ; if `c > 1000`,
    #f                            ;   exit the top loop ; or else,
    (let loopb ((b 1))            ; start the first-nested loop with b = 1,
      (if (> b c)                 ; if `b > c`,
        (loopc (+ c 1))           ;   end the first-nested loop, and
                                  ;   continue the top loop with c := c+1 ; or else,
        (let loopa ((a 1))        ; start the second-nested loop with a = 1,
          (if (> a b)             ; if `a > b`,
            (loopb (+ b 1))       ;   end the second-nested loop, and
                                  ;   continue the first-nested loop with b := b+1
            (begin                ; or else,
              (if condition       ;   if condition holds,
                (do_some a b c)   ;     do something with a, b, c,
                #f)               ;   and then,
              (loopa (+ a 1))     ;   continue the second-nested loop with a := a+1
              )))))))
```

Of course it's a bit involved and error prone. On the other hand it is easy to shortcut the innermost loop (on `a`s) and restart the top one (on `c`s) directly, by calling `loopc` from within `loopa` (always in *tail position*, NB !), should the need arise.

For example, the above code is directly applicable to the problem which you state in the comments, of finding a Pythagorean triplet which sums to 1000. Moreover, when you've hit upon the solution, you can directly call `(loopc 1001)` to immediately exit the whole threefold nested loops construction.

---

As a side note,

```py
for c in range(3, 1000):
    for b in range(2, c):
        for a in range(1, b):
            if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and a + b + c == 1000:
                print(a * b * c)
```

is not the most efficient solution. That would be, at least, first,

```py
for c in range(3, 1000):
    for b in range(2, 1000-c-1):
        for a in range(1, 1000-c-b):
            if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and a + b + c == 1000:
                print(a * b * c)
```

and furthermore,

```py
for c in range(3, 1000):
    c2 = c**2
    for b in range(2, 1000-c-1):
        a = 1000-c-b
        if a**2 + b**2 == c2:
                print(a * b * c)
                # exit the loops
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to express any kind of loop (and indeed much more general control structures) in Scheme.  For instance if you want a loop which simply counts you can do it like this:

```
(let loop ([i 0])
  (if (>= i 10)
      (values)
      (begin
        (display i)
        (loop (+ i 1)))))
```

And you can obviously nest these.

But this is a lot less easy to read than, for instance, what you would write in Python:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Well, OK.  But Lisp-family languages are *about building languages*: if the syntax you want does not exist, you *make it exist*.  Here is an example of doing that:

```
(define-syntax nloop*
  ;; Nested numerical loop
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ () form ...)
     (begin form ...
            (values))]
    [(_ ((variable lower-inclusive upper-exclusive) more ...) form ...)
     (let loop ([variable lower-inclusive])
       (if (< variable upper-exclusive)
           (begin
             (nloop* (more ...) form ...)
             (loop (+ variable 1)))
           (values)))]
    [(_ ((variable start-inclusive end-exclusive step) more ...) form ...)
     (let ([cmp? (if (>= step 0) < >)])
       (let loop ([variable start-inclusive])
         (if (cmp? variable end-exclusive)
             (begin
               (nloop* (more ...) form ...)
               (loop (+ variable step)))
             (values))))]))
```

And now:

```
> (nloop* ((i 0 10))
    (print i))
0123456789
```

But also

```
> (nloop* ((i 0 10)
           (j 20 0 -4))
    (displayln (list i j)))
(0 20)
(0 16)
(0 12)
(0 8)
(0 4)
...
(9 20)
(9 16)
(9 12)
(9 8)
(9 4)
```

So this `nloop*` construct I have just invented will do perfectly general numerical loops, including nested ones (this is why the `*`: `nloop` (which does not exist) would loop in parallel).

Of course in industrial-strength scheme-derived languages like Racket there are already constructs for doing this:

```
(for ([i (in-range 10)])
  (for ([j (in-range 20 0 -4)])
    (displayln (list i j))))
```

would be the idiomatic Racket way of doing this.  But `for` and all its variants and infrastructure are just language constructs that you could in principle write *yourself* in a very bare-bones Scheme.

These are languages which are designed for *building languages*.

Answer (score 0):

There are incredible many ways to cope with your problem.  Here is the simplest that passed in my mind now:

```
(define iota
  (lambda (n k)
    ((lambda (s) (s s 1))
     (lambda (s x)
       (k x)
       (or (= n x)
           (s s (+ x 1)))))))

(iota 1000
      (lambda (c)
        (iota c
              (lambda (b)
                (iota b
                      (lambda (a)
                        (newline)
                        (display a) (display " ")
                        (display b) (display " ")
                        (display c) (display " ")))))))
```

If the initial interval of `c` is `1..3` instead of `1..1000`, the nested code will contain these values of `(a b c)`:

```
a b c
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 2
2 2 2
1 1 3
1 2 3
2 2 3
1 3 3
2 3 3
3 3 3
```